# Fixed width div side by side with maximum width div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have one div that will be a menu bar of fixed size on the left. Then another div with the rest of the space on the right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title></title>
        <style>
                #header{
                    height:50px;
                    background-color:red;
                    border-radius:10px;
                }
                .left{
                    width:100px;
                    height:500px;
                    background-color:green;
                    border-radius:10px;
                    float:left;
                }
                .right{
                    background-color:lightskyblue;
                    border-radius:10px;
                    height:500px;
                    margin-left:100px;
                }
                #footer {
                    height:50px;
                    background-color:violet;
                    border-radius:10px;
                    clear:both;
                }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"></div>

        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">
            <h3>Andrew: The Resumé</h3>
            <p>Languages I know:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Arabic</li>
                <li>Java</li>
                <li>HTML</li>
                <li>CSS</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the closest I could get it, but the boxes are not even. Probably because I used float with one div but not the other. If I use float:left with both the width of the right div doesn't fill the rest of the screen. Help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a wrapper element around the elements that you want to be side by side, set to `display: table;`, and then set those child elements to be `display: table-cell;`

This way you can get rid of the `float` and `margin-left` on those elements, and they will sit neatly beside each other. This also has the benefit of making sure both elements have the same height, so even if you took the `height` properties off, they would remain constant (in relation to each other)

Check out this demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/zg6xt/

Comment: This works great, but how do I make the text go back into the top-left corner of the div?

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` will get the text to the top, if it is not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your left and right div in a container.

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">
            <h3>Andrew: The Resumé</h3>
            <p>Languages I know:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>Arabic</li>
                <li>Java</li>
                <li>HTML</li>
                <li>CSS</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

and in your css you would use float left and right. The container is used to contain its children from busting out all over the place. You can apply a clearfix on it and/or margin:0 auto depending on your situation. Apply to your now child divs:

```
.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
```

I hope this helps. I tend to have the left and right container both float left for responsive purposes and use dynamic widths (a.k.a percentages) Hope this gets you unstuck!